# ngFor does not render my obersavle response, but it does inset old values I add to the array?

Tags: angular, observable, ngfor

I'm working on a project for work and I want to update a list with new values that gets rendered with `ngFor`.

The array I want to update: `this.openedRecipe.Receptregels`

I get a response from my observale of an array with new Receptregels I want to add.

If I do

```
this.openedRecipe.Receptregels = [...this.openedRecipe.Receptregels, ...response];
```

or:

```
this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.push(response[0])
```

it will not add the new line(s) of my response in the view.

But when I do this for example:

```
this.openedRecipe.Receptregels = [...this.openedRecipe.Receptregels, ...this.openedRecipe.Receptregels[0]];
```

Or:

```
this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.push(his.openedRecipe.Receptregels[0])
```

It will add the old line as an extra line to my view...

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

The old way to fix this was to rerender the entire view and then when you open a Recipe, it will contain the new lines, since they got added in the backend to the recipe.

But I would like to show the new values without reloading the entire page

Comment: So you want the ngFor the be rendered again when your subscription gets new datas?

Comment: Basicly yes, but I want to add the new recipeLines I get from my observale response to the openedRecipe.Receptregels.  Only problem is, it will not render those lines. If I add duplicated of the recipeLines that are already inside the openedRecipe.Receptregels the duplicated once actualy will be rendered, also if I add them to the array inside the response block of my observable. But if I do the same thing with the new lines from the response they will not be added to the view?

Comment: Already tried this, but it did not work for me

Comment: Also it would not explain why the duplicated of old lines can be added (if I set them inside the resolved observable) and the new values from my response cannot be added on the exact same place in the TS file

Comment: because your response is `Observable<YourModel[]>` not the `YourModel[]`

Comment: what do `response` and `Receptregels`look like?

Comment: @Wolfyr you need to `subscribe` your observable response and inside `subscribe` function, you would push the new data received to your existing array.

Comment: Yes I cam doing it inside the subscription, but it only works for the old values, not the new values I get from my subscription for some reason... Did this like a 10000 times in other projects and never hjad this issue

Comment: can you post how your response model looks like in _Network Tab_ of browser?

Comment: along with that, it would really help in solving the problem if you could post the actual code.

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Sorry I cant post the full code, because its for work and I need to keep it secret, signed for it... you know the drill haha

Comment: @Wolfyr yeah, no worries :)

Comment: But the strange thing to me is, that I can add recipeLines that are already in the recipe (inside my subscription block), but for some reason I cannot add the new lines, well I can add them, but they will not display

Comment: @Wolfyr you said _I'm doing the same thing in my code only with a RxJS Subject._ what  exactly is `RxJS Subject` here? the array, response or what?

Comment: In my service:   

public updatedRecipe = new Subject<any>();

public splitRecipe(motherRecipeId: string, recipeId: string) {
    this.http.put(`${environment.apiEndpoint}/recipe/split/${motherRecipeId}`, {recipeId: recipeId})
        .subscribe(response => {
          this.responseValue = response;
          this.updatedRecipe.next(response);
        });
  }

Comment: In component:
splitLine(line: Receptregel, recipe: Recept) {
    console.log(this.openedRecipe);

    this.recipeService.splitRecipe(line._id, recipe._id);
    this.recipeService.updatedRecipe.subscribe(updatedRecipe => {
      console.log(this.openedRecipe.Receptregels);
      console.log(updatedRecipe.updatedRecipe.Receptregels);
      console.log(updatedRecipe.newLines);
      this.openedRecipe.Receptregels = [...this.openedRecipe.Receptregels, ...updatedRecipe.newLines]
      // this.rerender();
    }, err => console.log(err));
  }

Comment: `this.updatedRecipe.next(response);` this would simply overwrite the previous values. any specific need of doing it in this way?

Comment: Yes I do that in my service to keep everything immutable but for this specific route it is not realy needed, but I get the correct values I want inside my component subscription when I want to receive them

Comment: I believe I got the problem, let me try to post an online example with solution implemented.

Comment: Would be great :)

Comment: I also have an add new recipeLine function, here I do the same basicly, but there it's working, so waiting for your solution :)

Comment: have a look at this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkckxn)

Comment: @Wolfyr without your actual code, its really difficult to replicate the problem. I have used `BehaviorSubject` to retain the last values and also include them while adding new ones. You can adjust this code according to your need by moving the array part to component.

Comment: @Wolfyr please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!!!

I needed to assign my response to a variable and then push it into this.openedRecipe.Receptregels, if I do that it works, if not it does not work.

```
  splitLine(line: Receptregel, recipe: Recept) {
this.recipeService.splitRecipe(line._id, recipe._id);
this.recipeService.updatedRecipe.subscribe(updatedRecipe => {
  const newLine = updatedRecipe.newLines[0];
  const newLine2 = updatedRecipe.newLines[1];
  this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.push(newLine);
  this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.push(newLine2);
  }, err => console.log(err));
}
```

So basicly this works, will finetune it a bit more to be a bit neater, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what's the objects like in your project, I will use a simple example to do that.

Basically you have to `append` the new data to the old data you are getting from the subscription.

I've created a basic service that return `Observables` of a simply object:

```
export class AppService{
  public getOldData(){
    return Observable.of([
      {
        name: 'Mark'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jhon'
      },
      {
        name: 'Matt'
      }
      ]);
  }

  public getNewData(){
    return Observable.of([
      {
        name: 'Jimmy'
      },
      {
        name: 'Elys'
      },
      {
        name: 'Sarah'
      }
      ]);
  }
}
```

The component's code:

```
  oldData: any;

  constructor(private service: AppService){
    this.service.getOldData()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.oldData = res;
    });
  }

  public getNewData(){
    this.service.getNewData()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.oldData  = [...this.oldData, ... res];
    });
  }

<span (click)="getNewData()"> Click me to get new data!</span>
<hr>

<div *ngFor="let d of oldData">
  {{d.name}}
</div>
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdxldf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in my code only with a RxJS Subject. The thing that is not working for some reason is this:  this.oldData  = [...this.oldData, ... res];  and the only for the ...res,   if for example I do this this.oldData  = [...this.oldData, ...this.oldData[0]]; It will add a copy if this.oldData[0] to my view. But it will not add the lines of my res

Comment: I believe that your relative `res` is an array of array of objects, and not an array of objects. Can you check this?

Comment: Nope its an array of objects, check above I gave the values I get back and the value of the opendRecipe

Comment: `this.openedRecipe.Receptregels = [...this.openedRecipe.Receptregels, ...response];` -> debug this line with the chrome inspector, what's the data BEFORE and AFTER that assignment?

Comment: The data in thus.opendedRecipe is how I want it to be, it just does not display the lines from response

Comment: How  did you bind `this.openedRecipe.Receptregels` to the ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual code, its really difficult to replicate the problem. I have used `BehaviorSubject` to retain the last values while adding new ones. You can adjust this code according to your need by moving the `BehaviorSubject` part inside your `component`.

**Main Parts Of Code**

```
public updatedData = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

public getNewData(){
  const lastValues = this.updatedData.getValue();

  const newValues = [
    { name: 'Jimmy' },
    { name: 'Elys' },
    { name: 'Sarah' }
  ];

  this.updatedData.next([...lastValues || [], ...newValues]);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wkckxn)**

Comment: A behaviorSubject will not work for this function. I have no initial value to give the behaviorSubject. Also this would hold data of nu previosly opendedRecipe and remember the  last value and add it to the response of my next function Call, this will not work for me.. sorry

Comment: you can give initial value as `null`. "_remember the last value and add it to the response of my next function Call_" isn't this what you wanted to do?

Comment: Hey, no the function is to split one line into 2 duplicated and get the 2 duplicated back from the backend. Then replace the original line with the 2 duplicates. So no data needs to be remembered of the previous split. I just need to receive the 2 duplicate lines (whaqt I do get) and then switch the original line for the 2 duplicates

Comment: P.s. I do kind of the same thing in my addLine function, and here it works just fine...

addRecipeLine() {
    this.recipeService.createRecipeLine(<Receptregel>{
      ArtikelProductie: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.openedRecipe.Naam)),
      Versie: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.openedRecipe.Versie))
    }, this.openedRecipe._id ).subscribe(res => {
      const newLine = res.newLine;
      newLine.Prio = this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.length + 1;
      this.openedRecipe.Receptregels.push(newLine);
    });
  }

Comment: @Wolfyr I'm afraid I won't be of much help unless you can reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Thank you Syed, but I already solved it. I needed to reasign my response to variables before pushing them in the openedRecipe.Receptregels, for some reason it did not work without that. But now its working just fine :)  Thank you for all the effort anyway!!

Comment: It's not working... Only for one recipe.... Man never had this kind of weird non working but still kind of working code...

Comment: Starting to thinks it's an ngIf that keeps it from rendering

Comment: It was a combination of the 2. 1 ngIf that kept it from rendering and I needed to asign them to a variable before appending them. Now it works on all of them